# How to add a column to a table from another table in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-update, alter

I have two tables

1. table1
2. table2

Tabel1 contains 2 columns

1. id
2. Name

Tabel2 contains 2 columns

1. id
2. Age

A want to add age column from table2 to table1 (WHERE table1.id = table2.id)

Then table1 should contains 3 columns

1. id
2. Name
3. Age

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First add Age column in table1

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN Age TINYINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
```

then update that column using blow query

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN Tabel2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
SET t1.age = t2.age;
```

Comment: Yeah sure, copy my answer.

Comment: @fancyPants the timestamps suggest that Saharsh submitted his answer first.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk He edited his answer afterwards, after he saw mine.

Comment: @fancyPants did you even look at the edit? He only added a semicolon (which your solution doesn't even have). The two of you gave the same answer in the same minute. It happens. No hard feelings.

Comment: @MartinSchapendonk FYI, when you edit an answer in the first 5 minutes, you can't have a look at it later. Go ahead, have a try on your next answer, there won't be a `edited <datetime>` link in the first 5 minutes. But sure, defend him. Soon everyone writes a "asdf" answer first and edits later, just to be the first to answer.

Comment: @fancyPants if that is true, than that would be a very nasty way to hijack the first answer and I would take everything back I said earlier.

Comment: This is not working for me in adding the values into the table...

Comment: I'm using this answer, but I'm getting a Syntax error: Unexpected 'INNER'. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 107):

First add the column with the appropriate datatype.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN Age TINYINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0;
```

Then update the table, so that the values are "transmitted".

```
UPDATE table1 t1
INNER JOIN tabel2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
SET t1.Age = t2.Age
```

Comment: What is advantage of using `t1`, `t2`?

Comment: @Gathide Less typing :) I made it a habit to always add the table name to a column in a select clause for example. Short aliases help a lot here.

Comment: This is not working for me... I should also note that I did not alter the table which is the first line you have because I already have the column existing.. I don't know if that is what's causing issues... Any theories on that?