# Add Columns to Database1 from Database2

Tags: mysql

I have searched all the google and not yet found a solution. I seen some Joint functions etc in some sites but don't know how to do well.

I have table1 having 192 columns and 4000 records.

Table2 with 402 column and 0 records.

I need to add columns which is not present on table1 from table2. I found very hard to manually add column one by one.

Example:

Table1 (4000 records)
Columns: Name, Age, Gender

Table2 (0 records)
Columns: ID, Refferal_ID, Name, Age, Place, Gender, Country

I need to make Table3
Table3 (4000 records)
Columns: ID, Refferal_ID, Name, Age, Place, Gender, Country
(Let new column's value for each record to be 0)

Comment: You can use prepare a statement and execute un `alter table ...`. Check a look here, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html

Comment: @amaia Sorry, I am new to SQL did not understand how to implement. Can you describe briefly. [I saw this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27376152/how-to-add-a-column-to-a-table-from-another-table-in-mysql) but Actually I need to add columns not the data. Hard to add columns manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a column, you can create a procedure with a prepared statement using `prepareStmt`.

This is an example using prepared statements for add a column in a table:

```
SET v_column_definition := CONCAT(
  v_column_name
  ,' ',v_column_type
  ,' ',v_column_options 
);

SET @stmt := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN ', v_column_definition);

PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: How to get Column Name, type (60+) of respective columns to execute which is present on the other table. Also Is there any ready made tool or php scripts etc which can do this job. Give 2 tables will create a new table with both of table combined (all column and data)

Comment: you can do something like this and get the structure of the columns in any table `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE, IS_NULLABLE, COLUMN_DEFAULT
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE table_name = 'tbl_name'
  [AND table_schema = 'db_name']
  [AND column_name LIKE 'wild']`